# Application of Combinatorics/Graph Theory to Organic Chemistry?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, applications, chemistry

Recently, I have been self-teaching graph theory and having an organic chemistry course at school.

When I was learning isomer enumeration I found great resemblance between organic molecules and graphs. Every atom can be regarded as a vertex, with carbon vertices of $4$ degree, hydrogen atoms of $1$ degree etc. On the whole they just constitute a loopless yet usually not simple graph!

While I am excited about this idea, I am unclear about how to apply graph theory (and some combinatorial techniques) to chemistry.

Am I correct? Are there really applications of combinatorics or graph theory to organic chemistry, particularly isomer enumeration? If so how? Are there any books or resources from where I can learn about this amazing idea?

Comment: To get you started, how many different alkanes are there with $n$ C atoms?

Comment: @almagest I've thought about that, but I don't know how to solve this. There are just so many isomorphic graphs when counting, and I don't know how to deal with this problem.

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~sf34/local_fall07_pub.pdf) research abstract of interest, it starts by describing drug research that utilized combinatorics (and then goes on to talk almost exclusively about things called [polyhexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhex_%28mathematics%29), or *polycyclic
benzenoid hydrocarbons* as they're known to chemists). It's mostly about polyhexes, but might yield a reference or two (that you'd have to track down yourself; none are listed).

Comment: Alkanes: http://oeis.org/A000602 might get you started.

Comment: @almagest The information there is overwhelming. Can you tell me about it? Are there any formulas or recurrence relations?

Comment: I think you are straying into a different question!

Comment: @almagest Yes, but I just want to try it out, as an example.

Comment: Yes, RDKit has modules dealing with graphs, the reaction mechanism generator RMG uses it. The keyword is Cheminformatics.

Comment: You might be interested in"Combinatorial Enumeration of Groups, Graphs, and Chemical Compounds" by Polya and Read: http://www.amazon.com/Combinatorial-Enumeration-Groups-Chemical-Compounds/dp/1461291054/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1463838724&sr=8-1&keywords=polya+chemical+compounds

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there are quite a lot actually, see for example Trinajstic's book *Chemical Graph Theory*.

http://docdro.id/L3DrG6B
or
https://www.scribd.com/doc/313337501/Chemical-Graph-Theory-Trinajstic

To list some of the topics discussed in the book verbatim, we have for example:

- Kekule structures
- Hückel theory
- the conjugated circuit model
- Zagreb group
- Cayley generating function for enumerating isomers

Actually most (if not all) applications in that book seem to be exclusively for organic chemistry, so you have quite a lot to choose from.

Comment: The stuff by Balaban and associates is also of interest.